# AWS mqtt SQL query

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, mqtt

I have the following mqtt message:

```
{
  "sensors": [
    {
      "lsid": 412618,
      "data": [
        {
          "temp_in": 72.3,
          "heat_index_in": 72,
          "dew_point_in": 55.9,
          "ts": 1652785241,
          "hum_in": 56.3
        }
      ],
      "sensor_type": 243,
      "data_structure_type": 12
    },
    {
      "lsid": 421195,
}
```

I can get the "sensors,0.lsid" value and the entire "data" array using this query:

```
 select get(sensors,0).lsid as ls, get(sensors, 0).data as data1 from "topic"
```

but what I really need is to get "temp_in:72.3" , i.e. the values from the second level array
I've tried using this :[AWS Doc.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-sql-nested-queries.html), but unless I'm not following it correctly, it doesn't seem to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: are you using Redshift to perform the query?

Comment: No, I'm writing the query in the AWS IoT core rule creator, i will pass the result of the rule to a lambda function to write it into timestream